# Get V8 to retain debugging data

Tags: c++, v8

I am currently trying to debug V8, just in case anyone has any insights I will also explain the issue, but that is lateral to the question.

### Context

I have a bundled JavaScript file that works as a parser, so something like:

```js
let data = "3";
let po = new ParseOptions();
let ds = new DiagnosticSink();
let ps = new Parser().parseSourceFile(data, po, ds);
```

The fatal error happens when I call `.parseSourceFile`, however it only seems to happen when I have more than one token, i.e.: the above would be fine, but if `data` was `3 + 5` or `a = 3`, it would error. When running it via node, I just get a similarly looking AST (with more nodes).

The error is:

```
#
# Fatal error in ../../src/objects/intl-objects.cc, line 2478
# Debug check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffc0cb58460
==== C stack trace ===============================

    ./a.out() [0x182c9e6]
    ./a.out() [0x41966b]
    ./a.out() [0x181c90b]
    ./a.out() [0x181c935]
    ./a.out() [0x8215a0]
    ./a.out() [0x18e4379]
    ./a.out() [0x18eccbd]
    ./a.out() [0x12486ff]
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

### Question

I would like to use `gdb` to step though the code inside of V8 to see if I can make sense of that error, since looking at the [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/tags/9.7.106.18/src/objects/intl-objects.cc#2478) didn't help me understand the issue specifically. The issue is that it only displays ASM code, and I have made sure to compile V8 with the `is_debug=true` flag. Is there some other way I should be dubbing V8, and is there a way to build V8 such that I can use `gdb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

Using GDB with V8 is absolutely possible, the important GN arg is `v8_optimized_debug = false` (in addition to `is_debug = true`). If you use the [convenience workflow](https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn#gm) you get that automatically. There should be no further tricks necessary; though for increased convenience you may also want to include V8's [gdbinit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/main/tools/gdbinit) from your `~/.gdbinit`.

This does look like a bug in V8, so feel free to file a bug at [crbug.com/v8/new](https://crbug.com/v8/new) with repro instructions and someone from the team will take a look -- if it still happens with recent versions; 9.7 is quite old. Of course, if you can make further debugging progress on your end, that's great too, and we'd be more than happy to [accept a patch](https://v8.dev/docs/contribute).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have been able now to compile it properly and use the debugger. Although in the end the issue was a misconfiguration by me in the initialization!